# ASP.net MVC Hash password at the client side

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am developing a web application using the ASP.net MVC 5. Using form authentication. For the password field I use the `PasswordFor()` helper.

```
@Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
```

I also use the https, so everything is supposed to be encrypted at the transport level.

My questions are:

1. Why using Fiddler to check I can catch the "raw" password, the one I input?
2. Do I need to do something likes hash the password at client side before submitting back to the server?

Comment: What's the problem? You can see the password going to the server on your local dev machine? Or on the actual webserver with HTTPS and a correct cert?

Comment: Fiddler can also inject its own certificate so that it can see inside HTTPS (your browser should, if configured correctly, warn you about this certificate)

Comment: Hi Jamie R, yes, I use the self-sign certificate for the testing. The problem is some one "see" it by using the Fiddler. And according a security reason,  that is not good.

Comment: And I am asking for a something to hash the password at the client side.

Comment: So, its unsafe for your user to inject a custom certificate in order to see the password he just typed?
As said above, if a malicious program injects custom certificates and captures packets, the browser should be able to detect and warn the user, that part of security is up to the user, not your site. Also, that's why they invented 2-way authentication, lame, pitiful, enraging at times, but, safer.
You can encode the passwords with javascript as well, no problem, but, a potential hacker can easily get through your encoding algorithm to reverse it.